# Prove the trigonometric identity $(35)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that

\begin{equation}
\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=  \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
       \sqrt{n} \space \space \text{for $n$ odd}\\
       \\
        \ 1 \space \space \text{for $n$ even}\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}

I found this identity [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html) at$(35)$. At the moment I don't know where I should start from.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the identity $\tan(a+b)=...$ identity in reverse?

Comment: @picakhu: no. This sounds interesting. The generalization seems hard though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\tan nx=\frac{^nC_1t-^nC_3t^3+^nC_5t^5-\cdots }{^nC_0t^0-^nC_2t^2+^nC_4t^4-\cdots }$$ where $t=\tan x$

If $\tan nx=0, x=\frac {k\pi}n$  where $0\le k< n$, clearly, the roots of this $n$-degree equation are $\tan\frac{k\pi}n$

If $n$ is odd,

$^nC_n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}t^n+^nC_{n-2}(-1)^{\frac{n-3}2}t^{n-2}+\cdots-^nC_3t^3+^nC_1t=0$

$^nC_n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}t^{n-1}+^nC_{n-2}(-1)^{\frac{n-3}2}t^{n-3}+\cdots-^nC_3t^2+^nC_1=0$ if we exclude $k=0$

So, $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}$ (applying [Vieta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)'s formula)

Now, $\tan \left(\frac{(n-k) \pi}{n}\right)=\tan \left(\pi-\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=-\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$

So, there are $\frac{n-1}2$ such pairs and $\lfloor \frac{n-1}2  \rfloor=\frac{n-1}2$ as $n$ is odd.

$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$
$=(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan^2 \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right) $

$\implies (-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan^2 \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2} $

$\implies \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)\right)^2=n$

$\implies \prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=\sqrt n$ as all the angles lies in $(0,\frac \pi 2)$

If $n$ is even,

$ ^nC_1t^{n-1}-^nC_3t^{n-3}+^nC_5t^{n-5}-\cdots+^nC_{n-1}(-1)^{\frac n 2}t=0$ which has roots $\tan\frac{k\pi}n$ where $0\le k<n$ and $k\ne \frac n 2$ as $k=\frac n 2$ corresponds to $\tan \frac \pi 2(=\infty)$ which has occurred as the co-efficient of $t^n$ is $0$.

So, $ ^nC_1t^{n-2}-^nC_3t^{n-4}+^nC_5t^{n-6}-\cdots+^nC_{n-1}(-1)^{\frac n 2}=0$  if we exclude $k=0$ i.e., $(n-2)$ degree equation in $t$.

So, $$\prod_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\neq \frac{n}{2}}}^{n-1}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=-(-1)^{\frac n 2}$$

Now, $\tan \left(\frac{(n-k) \pi}{n}\right)=\tan \left(\pi-\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=-\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$

So, there are $\frac{n-2}2=(\frac n 2 -1)$ such pairs and $\lfloor \frac{n-1}2  \rfloor=\frac{n-2}2$ as $n$ is even.

$-(-1)^{\frac n 2}$
$={\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{k=1 \\ k \neq \frac{n}{2}}}^{n-1}} \tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$
$=(-1)^{\frac{n-2}2}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)\right)^2$

$\implies \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)\right)^2=1$

$\implies \prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=1$ as all the angles lies in $(0,\frac \pi 2)$

Comment: thanks!(+1). However, the point $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}$ doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: @Chris'ssister, could you please have a look into the modified answer?

Comment: oh, that's better now! Thanks.

Comment: @Chris'ssister, welcome! hope I could make the point clear.

Comment: like many others here, you're very skillful at math and I'm glad that you share your solutions with us. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This answer only presents the answers already given, but in what I hope is a more accessible form.

**Even n**

A key identity is $\tan(x)\tan(\pi/2-x)=1$. For $n$ even, this immediately verifies that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n/2-1}\tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=1\tag{1}
$$
**Odd n**

Since $\cos(nx)(1+i\tan(nx))=e^{inx}=(\cos(x)(1+i\tan(x)))^n$. Considering the ratio of the imaginary part to the real part, for odd $n$, we get 
$$
\tan(nx)=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{2k+1}\tan^{2k+1}(x)}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{2k}\tan^{2k}(x)}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k}=0\tag{3}
$$
has roots at $x\in\left\{\tan\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{n}\right):1\le k\le n-1\right\}$. Since $(3)$ has even degree, the product of the roots is the ratio of the constant coefficient to the lead coefficient:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{n}\right)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}n\tag{4}
$$
Another key identity is $\tan(\pi-x)=-\tan(x)$. Combined with $(4)$, this yields
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\tan\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\sqrt{n}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your work! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

I forgot that I had posted [an answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/220280), and answered [a duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474691) recently. Since this answer to the odd case is significantly different from the other answers, I have moved it here.

---

Note that
$$
\tan^2(\theta/2)=-\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}+1}\right)^2
$$
Therefore, for odd $n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\tan^2(k\pi/n)
&=\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}(-1)\left(\frac{e^{2\pi ik/n}-1}{e^{2\pi ik/n}+1}\right)^2\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi ik/n}-1}{e^{2\pi ik/n}+1}\right)\left(\frac{e^{-2\pi ik/n}-1}{e^{-2\pi ik/n}+1}\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi ik/n}-1}{e^{2\pi ik/n}+1}\right)\left(\frac{e^{2\pi i(n-k)/n}-1}{e^{2\pi i(n-k)/n}+1}\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{e^{2\pi ik/n}-1}{e^{2\pi ik/n}+1}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1-e^{2\pi ik/n}}{1+e^{2\pi ik/n}}\\
&=\lim_{z\to1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{z-e^{2\pi ik/n}}{z+e^{2\pi ik/n}}\\
&=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}\frac{z+1}{z^n+1}\\[12pt]
&=n
\end{align}
$$
Since tangent is positive in the first quadrant,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\tan(k\pi/n)=\sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial solution:**

Note that

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) \tan(x)=1$$

This solves the problem for $n$ even: if $n=2m$, then

$$P:=\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2  \rfloor}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{2m}\right) =\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\tan \left(\frac{(m-k) \pi}{2m}\right) $$

hence

$$P^2=\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\tan \left(\frac{k \pi}{2m}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\tan \left(\frac{(m-k) \pi}{2m}\right)=1$$

and since $P$ is positive, you are done...

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ even, [using](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

[image: this equation]

it is obvious since $\cos(\frac {\pi}{2}) = 0$