# Evaluation of a trigonometric series

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$$
\mbox{Question: Evaluate}\quad
\tan^{2}\left(\pi \over 16\right) + \tan^{2}\left(2\pi \over 16\right) + \tan^{2}\left(3\pi \over 16\right) + \cdots + \tan^{2}\left(7\pi \over 16\right)
$$

What I did:
Well I know that $\tan^{2}\left(7\pi/16\right)$ is the same as
$\cot^{2}\left(\pi/16\right)$. Thus this will repeat for all values up to
$\tan^{2}\left(4\pi/16\right)$.

However, I don't understand where to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

The 15 numbers $\tan k\pi/16$, $-7\leq k\leq7$, are the roots of the polynomial (of degree 15)
$(1+ix)^{16}-(1-ix)^{16}$ (using the geometric interpretation of complex numbers and their multiplication). The polynomial is of the form $-32ixp(x^2)$, where $p(t)=t^7-35t^6+\dots$ is a polynomial of degree 7, the roots of $p$ are thus $\tan^2 k\pi/2$, $1\leq k\leq7$. Your sum  is therefore $35$.

Comment: +1. I didn't check your solution in detail but it's is quite fine.

Comment: @FelixMarin, Have I committed any mistake to find the answer to be $35?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee it's me who made a mistake in the relevant coefficient, will repair it

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Use the half angle formula with $\theta = \pi/4$ to find $\tan(\pi/8)$ and do the same with $\theta = \pi/8$ to find $\tan(\pi/16)$

EDIT: The half angle formula is:
$$\tan(a) = \frac{2\tan(\frac{a}{2})}{1- \tan^2(\frac{a}{2})}$$
So use this formula for $a = \pi/4$ and $a = \pi/8$

Comment: What is the half angle formula?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question, should I take a to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{\pi}{8}$? Because if I take it to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$, I get zero in the denominator?

Comment: @Gummybears. First, $\pi/4$ in the lhs to get $\tan(\pi/8)$ solving the quadratic. Then repeat to get $\tan(\pi/16)$

Answer (score 0):

Like [Find $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{12}\tan \frac{k\pi}{13}\cdot \tan \frac{3k\pi}{13}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718346/find-sum-limits-k-112-tan-frack-pi13-cdot-tan-frac3k-pi13/720170#720170),

$$\tan16\theta=\frac{\binom{16}1t-\binom{16}3t^3+\cdots+\binom{16}{13}t^{13}-\binom{16}{15}t^{15}}{\cdots}\text{ where }t=\tan\theta$$

If $\displaystyle\tan16\theta=0,16\theta=r\pi$ where $r$ is any integer

$\displaystyle\implies\theta=\frac{r\pi}{16}$ where $0\le r\le15$

So, the roots of $\displaystyle\binom{16}1t-\binom{16}3t^3+\cdots+\binom{16}{13}t^{13}-\binom{16}{15}t^{15}=0$ are $\displaystyle\tan r\theta$ where $\displaystyle0\le r\le15,r\ne8$ as $\displaystyle\tan\frac{8\cdot\pi}{16}$ is not finitely defined

So, the roots of $\displaystyle\binom{16}1-\binom{16}3t^2+\cdots+\binom{16}{13}t^{12}-\binom{16}{15}t^{14}=0$

or of $\displaystyle\binom{16}{15}t^{14}-\binom{16}{13}t^{12}+\cdots+\binom{16}3t^2-\binom{16}1=0$

are $\displaystyle\tan r\theta$ where $\displaystyle1\le r\le15,r\ne8$

But as $\displaystyle\tan\frac{(16-n)\pi}{16}=\tan\left(\pi-\frac{n\pi}{16}\right)=-\tan\frac{n\pi}{16},\tan^2\frac{(16-n)\pi}{16}=\tan^2\frac{n\pi}{16};$

the roots of $\displaystyle\binom{16}{15}u^7-\binom{16}{13}u^6+\cdots+\binom{16}3u-\binom{16}1=0$ are $\displaystyle \tan^2\frac{(16-n)\pi}{16}=\tan^2\frac{n\pi}{16}$ where $1\le n\le 7$ or $9\le r\le15$

Now Vieta's formula is inviting