# Prove $\cot(x) +\cot(\frac{\pi}{3}+x) + \cot(\frac{2\pi}{3}+x) = \frac{3-9\tan^2x}{3\tan x-\tan^3x}$

Tags: trigonometry

As the title says. I tried simplifying the LHS but got:
$$\frac{\tan^2x+7\tan x- \sqrt{3}}{\tan^2x-\sqrt{3}}$$
What should I do next?

Comment: probably you made mistake [somewhere](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%5B++Cot%5Bx%5D+%2B++++Tan%5BPi%2F6+-+x%5D+%2B+%28-Sqrt%5B3%5D+%2B+7+Tan%5Bx%5D+%2B+Tan%5Bx%5D%5E2%29%2F%28+++Sqrt%5B3%5D+-+Tan%5Bx%5D%5E2%29+-+Tan%5BPi%2F6+%2B+x%5D%5D)

Comment: You can tell your simplification of the LHS must be incorrect by plugging in $x=0$:  $\tan0=0$, so the expression you got reduces to $1$, but the expression you're aiming at is infinite at $x=0$.

Comment: Yeah there's a mistake in my simplification. :)

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html), $\displaystyle\tan3x=\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$

$\displaystyle\implies\cot3x=\frac{1-3\tan^2x}{3\tan x-\tan^3x}\ \ \ \ (1)$

Multiplying the numerator & the denominator by $\cot^3x,$

$\displaystyle\cot3x=\frac{\cot^3x-3\cot x}{3\cot^2x-1}\ \ \ \ (2)$

If $\displaystyle\cot3x=\cot3A\iff\tan3x=\tan3A\implies3x=n\pi+3A$ where $n$ is any integer

$\displaystyle\implies x=\frac{n\pi}3+A$ where $n\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$

Usng
$\displaystyle(2),\frac{\cot^3x-3\cot x}{3\cot^2x-1}=\cot3x=\cot3A$

$\displaystyle\iff\cot^3x-3\cot3A\cot^2x-3\cot x+\cot3A=0$

Using Vieta's formula, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^2\cot\left(\frac{n\pi}3+A\right)=\frac{3\cot3A}1=3\cdot\frac{1-3\tan^2A}{3\tan A-\tan^3A}$ (using $(1)$)

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218766/prove-the-trigonometric-identity-35