# Prove Tan π/(2n + 1) Tan 2π/(2n + 1) Tan 3π/(2n + 1) .... Tan nπ/(2n + 1) = √(2n + 1)

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

Tan π/(2n + 1) Tan 2π/(2n + 1) Tan 3π /(2n + 1) .... Tan nπ /(2n + 1) = √(2n + 1

Dividing by √ (2n + 1)

(Tanπ/(2n + 1) Tan2π/(2n + 1) Tan 3π /(2n + 1) .... Tan nπ/(2n + 1))/(√(2n + 1)) = 1

To be equal to 1, the top term must be 1 or equal to (√ (2n + 1)

Putting

1 = tg (pi / 4) = tg45th
(Tanπ/(2n + 1) Tan2π/(2n + 1) Tan 3π / (2n + 1) .... Tannπ/(2n + 1)) = opposite collared
(√(2n + 1) = adjacent collet

Note that in a rectangular triangle if it is an angle is 45º, the other is also, characterizing the triangle as isosceles, both sides are equal, so (Tan π/(2n + 1) Tan2π/(2n + 1) Tan 3π/(2n + 1) .... Tan nπ/(2n + 1)) = (√ (2n + 1)

Can anyone show me anything better than this? (other than complex) or Who can prove using De Moivre's formula?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Comment: How can this fit in here?

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Another possible duplicate is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218766/prove-the-trigonometric-identity-35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the identity that
$$\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)=\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}+1\right).\left(x^2-2x \cos\frac {4\pi}{2n+1}+1\right).... \left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2n\pi}{2n+1}+1\right). $$
Let us take limit $x\rightarrow 1$, we get
$$2^{2n}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n+1} \sin^2 \frac{2\pi}{2n+1}...\sin^2 \frac{n\pi}{2n+1}=(2n+1)~~~~~~(1).$$
Next take limit $x \rightarrow -1$, we get
$$2^{2n}\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2n+1} \cos^2 \frac{2\pi}{2n+1}...\cos^2 \frac{n\pi}{2n+1}=1~~~~~~(2).$$
By dividing (1) by (2) and taking square root, we get
$$\tan \frac{\pi}{2n+1} \tan \frac{2\pi}{2n+1}...\tan \frac{n\pi}{n+1}=\sqrt{(2n+1)}~~~~~~(3).$$